# CC Before a date ie: CC 1788 on old Documents indicating a date of death?

Tags: abbreviations

I am doing Genealogy Research. The [U.S., newspaper extractions from the Northeast, 1704-1930](http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=50015), indicates CC before a death date. What does CC stand for?

Comment: Do you happen to have a link, or an image, that you could share?

Comment: This would probably get better answers on http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It stands for circa.  This is not specific to genealogy but dates in general.

Comment: I've never seen *cc* for *circa;* it's always been *ca.* or just *c.*

Comment: Have you contacted the source?

Comment: Obviously that's when his carbon copy died.

Comment: Were these scanned. Could "cc" be a scanning mistake for "ca"?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that [CC](https://www.geni.com/projects/Abbreviations-Acronyms-for-Genealogy-The-Accepted/3096) in regard to genealogy could stand for County Court (USA) County Clerk; county court, county commissioner; company commander. In the usage stated in the question, I believe County Court is likely

Comment: These were "Newspaper Extractions, 1704-1930".  While Herman Hollerith invented the standard punched card ca 1890, the ISO date format scheme was not made official until 1988, and the character codes you describe were not likely to have been used informally prior to about 1975.

Comment: While I understand the reference I cited is an ISO date format, I thought that the century reference might fit. However I found a better reference from an actual genealogy site. CC - County Court (USA) County Clerk; county court, county commissioner; company commander. https://www.geni.com/projects/Abbreviations-Acronyms-for-Genealogy-The-Accepted/3096

Comment: Edit your answer to be that instead, and you might get some votes.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking any further information from the OP (original poster), the best we can guess is that it is an OCR misreading of "ca" for "circa".  Such an OCR misreading would be fairly common.

Answer (score 0):

Those were NOT *death* dates. C.C. stands for **[Columbian Centinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbian_Centinel)**, and the date is when the information (in your case, an obituary) was printed:

> Elijah Elmer, died 28 Dec 1833, at Newfane, Vermont, age 80 (1)
>   Elmer, Elijah, rev. soldier, d. in Newfane, Vt., aged 80 yrs. (C.C. Jan 8, 1834) (2)
>
> Sources:
>   (1) Newspaper Extractions from the Northeast, 1704-1930, Ancestry dot com.
>   (2) Columbian Centinel, Pub. 8 Jan 1834, Massachusetts, Call No.: 485704
>   <sub>[Find a grave](http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=144537132)</sub>

Another example:

> U.S., Newspaper Extractions from the Northeast, 1704-1930
>   Name: Peter Wheeler
>   Birth Year: abt 1778
>   Event: Death
>   Death Date: Abt 1810
>   Newspaper: Columbian Centinel
>   Publication Date: 26 May 1810
>   Publication Place: Massachusetts, USA
>   Transcription: Wheeler, Peter d.in Petersham, aged 32 (C.C.May 26, 1810)
>   <sub>[The Sprague Project](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XrpG8uMhDPIJ:https://www.sprague-database.org/genealogy/getperson.php%3FpersonID%3DI409877%26tree%3DSpragueProject+&cd=20&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)</sub>

It's also true for marriage announcements:

> Ancestry.com. U.S., Newspaper Extractions from the Northeast, 1704-1930
>   Name:       Captain Elisha Hall
>   Event:       Marriage
>   Marriage Date:       Abt 1834
>   Marriage Place:       Hyannis
>   Spouse:       Polly B Lewis
>   Newspaper:       Columbian Centinel
>   Publication Date:       10 May 1834
>   Publication Place:       Massachusetts, USA
>
> "Hall, Elisha Capt., m. Mrs. Polly B. Lewis, in Hyannis (CC, May 10, 1834)."
>   <sub>[Hall Families of New England](http://www.johnlisle.com/newenglandhall/genealogy/getperson.php?personID=I10445&tree=NewEnglandHall)</sub>

---

(This answer is the product of my own research, but it's worth noting that [Steve](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/366338/191178) reached the same conclusion.)

Answer (score -1):

It stands for the Massachusetts  newspaper- Columbia Centinal and c.c. date is publish date paper had obituary.

[Columbian Centinel (Boston, Massachusetts) Newspaper Archives (1790 - 1840)](https://www.genealogybank.com/explore/newspapers/all/usa/massachusetts/boston/columbian-centinel)

Comment: Would you be so kind as to leave a link and/or citation to strengthen your answer?

Comment: Some of the information contained in this post requires additional [references](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Please [edit] to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: I added a source and link, but the dates don't quite jibe.